# Adding DSS to a pdf makes it invalid

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

I'm working on a PDF Signer/Validator and I'm using Itext7.

First I sign the pdf using the signDetached method from Itext7 :

```
signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, crlClients, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0, signatureType);
```

Second I add LTV info using these lines of code :

```
PdfReader   reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest2);
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer, new 
    StampingProperties().useAppendMode());

LtvVerification v = new LtvVerification(pdfDoc);
SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDoc);

List<String> names = signatureUtil.getSignatureNames();
String sigName = names.get(names.size() - 1);

for (String name : names){
    v.addVerification(name, ocsp, crl, LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
        LtvVerification.Level.OCSP_CRL, LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.YES);
}

v.merge();
```

At this point the file is signed and DSS is added. but when I try to validate the file here where the problem comes, I'm using Itext7 method to verify that the signature covers the whole document :

```
signatureUtil.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name);
```

But it keeps failing because the signature does not covers all the document although the file is not altered after signing only the DSS info is added and after more digging I found that the checkWhetherSignatureCoversWholeDocument() method inside the signatureCoversWholeDocument() method is the reason why it fails when it comes to check the byte ranges

```
this.tokens.getSafeFile().length() == (long)(byteRange[2] + byteRange[3])
```

This check always fail and that is the reason why it says that the file does not covers all document.

So what is wrong here, am I missing something ? All I need is to sign the file, add DSS and be able to validate this signature that it covers all the document .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved it by using signDeferred method instead of signDetached.

The problem occurs when trying to add DSS to the pdf dictionary after signing because it's considered as Editing the file after signing it so the signature does not covers the whole document anymore.

The solution was to use signDeferred method, It works by first use signExternalContainer method to modify the pdf dictionary and leave a blank placeholder for the signature to be added lately, then use the signDeferred method to fill this blank placeholder with the signature.

Check the official IText7 documentation for the signDeferred method :
[IText7 signDeferred](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/digital-signatures-chapter-4#Digitalsignatureschapter4-c4_09_deferredsigning)

The documentation shows how to sign using signDeferred but without adding crl or timestamp to the DSS so you can check my implementation [here](https://github.com/OmarRaed/digital-signature-samples/blob/main/SignDeferred) for adding crl and embedded timestamp with signDeferred method.

Comment: In your question you asked for a way to sign a PDF and then add DSS while the signature still is verified to cover the whole document (which is impossible). Your solution effectively does it the other way around, it first retrieves validation related information and adds them to the PDF and then signs. In contrast to the former this _is_ possible. But depending on the validation model applied to your signature, those validation related information may not be usable for validation. (Adobe Acrobat will usually use those information while a validator for EU qualified signatures must not do so.)

Answer (score 1):

> So what is wrong here, am I missing something ? All I need is to sign the file, add DSS and be able to validate this signature that it covers all the document.

But exactly this obviously is impossible.

When you have a signed PDF and add verification information to it, then you do this by adding an incremental update to the PDF carrying these data.

Now obviously the signature does not cover the full document anymore, in particular it does not cover the incremental update with the verification information.

So, what is wrong here, is your expectation that after adding something to a signed PDF, the signature would still cover the full document.

And another error is that you think that a signature not covering the full document is invalid.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought but there is a case that the file contains DSS and the signature still covers the whole document and I found a file covering this case, so how can I achieve it ?

Comment: *"there is a case that the file contains DSS and the signature still covers the whole document"* - Well, you can add a **DSS** dictionary to a PDF in the same revision (or even in a prior one) as the signature.  Adobe Acrobat will use the information therein if they are not much older than the signature. Beware, though: validators that validate by the ETSI specifications will not use those information.